# Conformal Map Question

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint on how to map the entire plane with cuts from [-1,1] and [-i,i] to the outside of the circle. I'm having trouble figuring out the first map to begin with :( . Any hints would be appreciated and please don't give the full solution!

Thanks in advance,
Starving Grad

Answer (score 1):

$z\mapsto \frac1z$ gives you for slits to infinity. Do you recall that $z\mapsto z+\frac1z$ maps the outside of the disk to the complement of $[-2,2]$?

Answer (score 0):

Using the eight steps listed within [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179208), we can map John's domain to the lower half-plane $-\mathbb{H}.$ The aim is to have $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ in the end, i.e. the exterior of the unit circle.

We can do this in three steps. Let $J(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$ with domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}$. The map $J$ is conformal, one-one onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-2,2].$ We will use its inverse $J^{-1}$ as the final step.

0. The starting point is $-\mathbb{H}.$
1. By applying $z \mapsto z^2,$ we obtain the entire plane with the origin and the positive real axis removed.
2. By applying $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{2z-2}{z+1},$ we get $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-2,2].$
3. Last of all we apply $J^{-1}.$