# Conformally map Swiss cross domain to a half-plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, conformal-geometry

Let $\Omega$ be the complex plane with the real interval $[-1,1]$ removed and with the purely imaginary interval $[-i,i]$ removed. (This domain has appeared at least once before: [Conformal Map Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413880) .)

I am comfortable with the following tool-kit: $\log$ and $\exp$; Linear fractional transformation a.k.a Möbius map; $z \mapsto z^r$ with $r>0$ and rational; the map $z \mapsto z + \frac{1}{z}$; the map $z \mapsto \sin z.$ With these tools I can solve most simple conformal mapping problems.

I have come up with eight steps which when composed, map $\Omega$ onto a half-plane; see below.

My question is, can I stream-line my solution to perhaps use fewer primitive steps? I'd like to know if my tool-kit is missing a useful tool.

Or if my toolkit is good enough, can I avoid using $z \mapsto z + \frac{1}{z}$ and the square root each one repeatedly in my eight steps? Maybe the order in which I apply my primitive maps is not the best. (*Also if you spot an error in my solution, please point it out.*)

0. The starting point is the unit "plus sign" or "Swiss cross".
1. By applying $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{i-z}{z+i},$ the cross becomes an infinite fork;  $[-1,1]$ becomes the right unit half-circumference, while $[-i,i]$ becomes the positive real axis.
2. We map the fork to a frog face via a square root, choosing the branch $\{0<\theta<2\pi\}\mapsto\{0<\frac{\theta}{2}<\pi\}.$
3. Now apply $z \mapsto z + \frac{1}{z}$; the boundary is now the real axis, excepting the interval $(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)$.
4. Next we stretch and shift with $z \mapsto \frac{z-\sqrt2}{2 \sqrt 2}$; the boundary is now the real axis, excepting the interval $(-1,0)$.
5. Apply the same branch of square root used already in step 2; now we have the upper half-plane with the ray $[i,\infty)=\{x=0,y \geq 1\}$ removed.
6. Now use the linear fractional map $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i};$ this gives us the unit disc with $[0,1)$ removed.
7. Apply the same branch of square root already used twice; now we have the upper half-unit disc.
8. Last of all apply $z \mapsto z + \frac{1}{z}$; we obtain the lower half-plane $-\mathbb{H}.$

Comment: If we start with the unit disk $\mathbb D$, then, with your choice of the square root, $f(z) = \sqrt {(z^2 + 1/z^2)/2}$ maps $\mathbb D \cap \mathbb H$ to $\Omega \cap \mathbb H$. Then the analytic continuation of $f$ to $\mathbb D \setminus \{0\}$, which is an odd function, maps $\mathbb D \setminus \{0\}$ to $\Omega$ (note that $\Omega$ will have to be defined as $\overline {\mathbb C} \setminus ([-1, 1] \cup [-i, i])$ to make it simply connected).

Comment: I did not think to use continuation; this is a different point of view, thank you. I will need to review analytic continuation a bit. I have verified that $f$ takes the half-disc to $\Omega \cap \mathbb{H},$ bijectively.  @Maxim